# Cypher query to find nodes that are not related to other node by property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider the following DB structure:

[image: DB structure]

For your convenience, you can create it using:

```
create (p1:Person {name: "p1"}),(p2:Person {name: "p2"}),(p3:Person {name: "p3"}),(e1:Expertise {title: "Exp1"}),(e2:Expertise {title: "Exp2"}),(e3:Expertise {title: "Exp3"}),(p1)-[r1:Expert]->(e1),(p1)-[r2:Expert]->(e2),(p2)-[r3:Expert]->(e2),(p3)-[r4:Expert]->(e3),(p2)-[r5:Expert]->(e3)
```

I want to be able to find all `Person` nodes that are *not* related to a specific `Expertise` node, e.g. "Exp2"

I tried

```
MATCH (p:Person)--(e:Expertise)
WHERE NOT (e.title = "Exp2")
RETURN p
```

But it returns all the `Person` nodes (while I expected it to return only `p3`).

Logically, this result makes sense because each of these nodes is related to at least one `Expertise` that is not `Exp2`.
But what I want is to find all the `Person` nodes that are not related to `Exp2`, even if they are related to other nodes as well.

How can this be done?

**Edit**

It appears that I wasn't clear on the requirements. This is a (very) simplified way of presenting my problem with a much more complicated DB.
Consider the possibility that `Expertise` has more properties which I would like to use in the same query (not necessarily with negation). For example:

```
MATCH (p)--(e) 
WHERE e.someProp > 5 AND e.anotherProp = "cookie" AND NOT e.title = "Exp2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little change query from @ChristopheWillemsen:

```
MATCH (e:Expertise) WHERE e.someProperty > 5 AND NOT e.title = someValue
WITH collect(e) as es
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE all(e in es WHERE NOT Exists( (p)--(e) ) )
RETURN p
```

UPDATE:

```
// Collect the `Expertise` for which the following conditions:
MATCH (e:Expertise) WHERE e.num > 3 AND e.title = 'Exp2'
WITH collect(e) as es

// Select the users who do not connect with any of of expertise from `es` set:
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person) WHERE all(e in es WHERE NOT Exists( (p)--(e) ) )
RETURN es, collect(p)
```

Another query with some optimization:

```
// Get the set of `Expertise-node` for which the following conditions:
MATCH (e:Expertise) WHERE e.num > 3 AND e.title = 'Exp2'

// Collect all `Person-node` connected to node from the `Expertise-node` set:
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)--(p:Person)
WITH collect(e) as es, collect(distinct id(p)) as eps

//Get all `Person-node` not in `eps` set:
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person) WHERE NOT id(p) IN eps
RETURN es, collect(p)
```

Comment: Specifically, If you add property `num` to each `Expertise` like `{title: "Exp1", num: 3}, {title: "Exp2", num: 4}, {title: "Exp3", num: 5}`, and using your query I use `MATCH (e:Expertise) WHERE e.num > 3 AND NOT e.title = "Exp2" WITH collect...`, I get `p1` as a result instead of `p3`.

Comment: That's interesting (and working). What you're suggesting, if I understand correctly, is to first match the negation of my condition, and then collect all the `Person` nodes that *don't* match it. Pretty cool.

Comment: @yarons An added bonus to this query is that you can operate with a set of expertise allocated on conditions (for example only those expertise where `e.num > 3` )

Comment: Yeah, I got that, thank you. That's a very good answer. I'm waiting to see if anyone can come up something even better before I grant the bounty, but this is definitely something I can work with.

Comment: @yarons Add another version of query for options when little person in relationships with each expertise.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE

You need to restrict it a bit more, meaning to only the person

```
MATCH (p:Person), (e:Expertise {title="Exp2"})
WHERE NOT (p)-[]->(e)
RETURN p
```

I think you will be just fine with the `<>` operator :

```
MATCH (p:Person)--(e:Expertise)
WHERE e.title <> "Exp2"
RETURN p
```

Or you can express it in a pattern :

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((p)--(e:Expertise {title:"Exp2"}))
RETURN p
```

Comment: First one does exactly the same, and the second throws an error

Comment: Your latest addition does work, but it's not quite what I need. I simplified the problem for the sake of the question, but imagine that `Expertise` has more properties, and in the same query I want to check something about them. Like `MATCH (p)--(e) WHERE e.someProperty > 5 AND NOT e.title = someValue`

Comment: Please amend your question then