# Cypher query to find nodes with some relationship(s), but not others

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Similar to [Cypher query to find nodes that are not related to other node by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463790/cypher-query-to-find-nodes-that-are-not-related-to-other-node-by-property), but different enough to stump me so far.

[image: Persons, Languages, and Tasks]

A Person is eligible for a Task if they meet the Language requirement and doesn't already have a relationship to it (*e.g.*, doing or rejected).

Tasks can depend on each other and 'inherit' their language through 0 or more `DEPENDS_ON` rels and the 'root' Task's `REQUIRES`.

I'm trying to create a query that will find that…

- `p1` is eligible for `t2` and `t4`
- `p2` is eligible for all 4
- `p3` is not eligible for any

Not even worrying about `t1`'s done-ness yet, I don't think I'm getting through/past the Language 'inheritance.'

For example, for `p2`:

`MATCH (p:Person {name: 'p2'})-[:SPEAKS]->(lang)
WITH p, collect(lang) AS langs
MATCH (t:Task)-[:DEPENDS_ON*0]->(:Task)-[:REQUIRES]->(lang:Language)
WHERE lang IN langs
RETURN t`

finds 0 rows

`MATCH (p:Person {name: 'p2'})-[:SPEAKS]->(lang)
RETURN lang`

gets both Languages, so I'm (pretty?) sure that `collect(lang) as langs` is what I want.

Removing the `:DEPENDS_ON*` links

`MATCH (p:Person {name: 'p2'})-[:SPEAKS]->(lang)
WITH p, collect(lang) AS langs
MATCH (t:Task)-[:REQUIRES]->(lang:Language)
WHERE lang in langs
RETURN t`

gets me `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.

How can I get `t4`, too?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse paths much more flexibly than that. Finding the path from a person to a task through a shared language node is all one path pattern, even if different instances of the path can route through separate languages. You can then extend it using a 0+ variable length path to find tasks that depend on a given task. Finally, filter out any paths where the task relates back to the person using one of the invalid. relationships.

```
MATCH (p:Person) - [:SPEAKS] -> (:Language) <- [:REQUIRES] - (:Task) <- [:DEPENDS_ON*0..] - (t:Task)
WHERE NOT (t) <- [:IS_DOING|:REJECTED] - (p)
RETURN p, COLLECT(DISTINCT t)
```